# How can I find all monitor purchases (not with monitor ID value, instead should use the term 'Monitor')

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, product-quantity

I have two tables,

[image: Products]

[image: Orders]

I need to find all monitor purchases (but not with monitor ID, instead I should use 'Monitor'). I have made code, but it takes the quantity for all products, not only for 'Monitor'.

The code I made:

```sql
select name, Price,sum(quantity)
from Products, Orders
where name='Monitor'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and expected results as text and not images to clarify what you want.

Comment: You need to properly join Products and Orders instead of using a cross join.

Comment: Can you please provide the table as text, not images? You can [edit (change) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69872351/edit). (But please do it ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the rows of both tables. Right now you are creating the cartesian product, containing every row from the first table combined with every row from the second table. With your screenshot, that's going to be 9 rows in total.

```
SELECT name, Price, SUM(quantity)
FROM Products, Orders
WHERE name='Monitor'
AND Products.ProductId = Orders.ProductId
```

Or use `JOIN` directly to separate the filter condition from the join condition:

```
SELECT name, Price, SUM(quantity)
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Products.ProductId = Orders.ProductId
WHERE Products.name='Monitor'
```